How do you position a footer to the bottom of a page in vue3?
I'm working on my first portfolio and I'm having trouble getting the footer to position at the bottom of the page when the browser window is shortened, as well as understanding how margins work/don't work.
App.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterLink, RouterView } from 'vue-router'
import Footer from './components/ComponentFooter.vue'
</script>

<template>
  <div id="topBar">
    <nav>
      <div class="navLeft">
        <RouterLink to="/">LoganCTanner</RouterLink>
      </div>
      <div class="navRight">
        <RouterLink to="/projects">projects</RouterLink>
        <RouterLink to="/hobbies">hobbies</RouterLink>
        <RouterLink to="/contact">contact</RouterLink>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <RouterView />
  <Footer />
</template>

<style>
#topBar {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 64px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.navLeft {
  color: white;
}

.navRight {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 32px;
}

nav a.router-link-exact-active {
  color: var(--vt-c-white);
}

nav a.router-link-exact-active:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

nav a {
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
}
</style>

ComponentFooter.vue
<script setup lang="ts"></script>

<template>
  <footer>
    <p>have a nice day :)</p>
    <div class="contactIcons"></div>
  </footer>
</template>

<style>
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

footer > p {
  margin: 0rem 1rem;
}
</style>

base.css
:root {
  --section-gap: 160px;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  color: var(--color-text);
  background: var(--color-background);
  transition:
    color 0.5s,
    background-color 0.5s;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-family: neue75;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  overflow: scroll;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: neue75;
  src: url(../../public/fonts/NHaasGroteskTXPro-75Bd.ttf);
}

main.css
@import './base.css';

#app {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-weight: normal;
}

nav .navLeft a:first-of-type {
  color: white;
}

nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkgray;
  transition: 0.4s;
  padding: 3px;
}

@media (hover: hover) {
  a:hover {
    color: lightgray;
  }
}


For the past few hours I've been tinkering with various combinations of margin and position on various elements, as well as where I'm importing the footer component, but nothing I've tried has worked.
Currently it's placing the footer over the bottom of the lorem ipsum filler div, and when I try adding margin to the bottom of the filler div it extends the bottom of the page, but the footer remains in the same position placed over the last line of the filler div instead of at the bottom of the page.
What I'm attempting to do is have the footer placed at the bottom using absolute, not fixed, and leave some room above the footer.

Do you want to have it absolute to another element or at the end of your website (as the title suggests)? Also I have no idea what you mean by "when the browser window is shortened". If you want the footer to always be the last element just keep it relative and place it last in your html-markup. To also keep it at the bottom of the screen in case you do not have enough content you can create e.g. a flex-container with height: 100vh, flex-direction: column and justify-content: space-between

I tried your suggestion and it just places the footer in the middle of the filler lorem ipsum div

Did you remove the position: absolute from the footer element and did you ensure that your #app actually spans the full browser window height? Please provide a codepen or update the question
